# jQuery disable checkboxes on rows matching join condition

Tags: jquery

So I have these rows of data and I need to disable checkboxes where column #3 contains 'B' OR column #4 contains negative number. I have a working code here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/2727/), but I feel like it redundant and not efficient. Could someone help with better way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#row1 tr > td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {

        if ($(this).text() == 'B')
        {
          $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').attr("disabled",true);
        }

    });

    $('#row1 tr > td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {

        if (parseInt($(this).text()) < 0)
        {
          $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').attr("disabled",true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Should this question go to code review?

Answer (score 0):

You may combine the 2 statements under a single selector for #row1 tr.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/2728/

```
<table id="row1">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr1">
            <td class="cb"><input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
                </td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>    
        <tr id="tr2">
            <td class="cb"><input type="checkbox" id="cb2">
                </td>
            <td>Y</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>    
        <tr id="tr3">
            <td class="cb"><input type="checkbox" id="cb3"> 
                </td>
            <td>Z</td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td>-3</td>  
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<p id="out"></p>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#out').text('');
    $('#row1 tr').each(function (i, o) {
        var node;
        if (i == 1) {
            node = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)");
            if($.trim($(node).text()) == "B")
                $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("disabled", true);
        }
        else if (i == 2) {
            node = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)");
            if (parseInt($(node).text()) < 0) {
                $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("disabled", true);
            }
        }
    });

    //get row values
    $('#out').append($('#row1 tr :checkbox:disabled').length);

});
```

Comment: This doesn't work when I replace 5 with -5 on the first